# How did Martha Kent modify the Kryptonian blanket that became Superman's costume?

Tags: dc, superman, costume

From my comment on this question/answer [Why wasn't Superman naked when he was lifting Luthor's artificial continent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22723/why-wasnt-superman-naked-when-he-was-lifting-luthors-artificial-continent/22724#comment41817_22724)

Supposedly the blanket is made of a super strong fabric, which is why it can withstand so much abuse; but if the material is so durable, how was Martha Kent able to tailor it into a form fitting costume?

[Thaddeus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22728/1148) says:

> Martha Kent unwove the Kryptonian fabric and rewove it into his costume. It was indestructible, didn't get dirty or torn and neither did his cape. She also created the S-shield.

Wouldn't her scissors break (or her hand) from the effort of trying to cut/tear/disassemble it?

Comment: I submit to you Exibit A: the never talked about first-aid kit Jor-El would have stashed in Kal-El's rocket. The little scissors went right into Martha's sewing kit.

Comment: Perhaps it needed to absorb the yellow sun rays to become invulnerable and she just kept it in a box in the dark in her attic till Clark became Superman.

Comment: Unweaving is not cutting.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Martha Kent was said to have unwoven the fabrics he was wrapped in and rewoven them into his only costume. The costume was indestructible except to Kal-El's heat vision, which was how she was said to have cut the material, when necessary. In this version of the character, baby Kal-El was so hard on his clothing due to his powers manifesting as a child, he was unable to wear anything except materials woven from those fabrics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is a fast and good answer O.O

Comment: Who the heck is he telling this to, and why does he know his own future??

Comment: This was done as part of a series called the Superboy Legend. This was a common thing done during the period because the comics were both numerous and often had unconnected (and sometimes conflicted) stories. This was one of the early attempts to help readers keep up.

Comment: Where did all the extra yellow material go?

Comment: I think its great you added this for authenticity but I'm leaning toward thinking this is more of a child's story book that was some side project of the franchise for kids rather than the typical comic. Is this straight from the comic book?

Comment: Yes it is straight from a comic. It was not a separate franchise book, it was not an imaginary story. It was written in the canon to explain how Superman's costume came to be nigh invulnerable.

Comment: @JackBNimble Martha Kent used the rest to make new super-curtains for young Clark's super-bedroom.