# What else did Pa Kent salvage from Jor-El's son's rocket?

Tags: dc, superman

According to DC Comics, beyond the baby and the blankets that were destined to make up Superman's future uniform, what else did Pa Kent salvage from baby Kal-El's spaceship?

Comment: Jor-El's infant son.

Comment: @Xantec Edited. Facepalmed as well :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where did Superman get his boots?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/where-did-superman-get-his-boots)

Comment: @Thaddeus That question, and its answers do not limit retrieved articles to just the boots' material.  Whether or not there was more material would be discovered in an answer to this uniquely- although it may be helpful to reference the question as _part_ of an answer.  Good find.

Comment: Depending on which version of the character you study, The Kent's salvaged a variety of things. Most of the time the Silver Age Superman is the one where the most was salvaged, Glass from the ship became Superman's glasses, cloth his costume, and plastic from the ship became his boots. Other iterations occasionally allow knowledge crystals (Smallville) or in the new DCNU, entire technologies were harvested to be used against Superman. It really depends on the editorial mandates of the period.

Comment: Progressive rocket insurance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonically, various items were removed from the pod found by Pa Kent;

In addition to the swaddling robes he also used the seatbelt, rubber lining from the seating, etc. to make superman's "[super suit](http://screenrant.com/superman-man-of-steel-suit-costume-history-versions/)"

Obviously (as with most DC comics) this differs depending on which origin story you choose.
In several stories his glasses are made out of Kryptonian crystal which is described as having a hypnotic effect...

[image: Superman's Outfit]
[image: Superman's Outfit 2]
[image: Superman's Outfit 3]

In the Christopher Reeves films (as well as the newest 'Smallville' series), he also finds a set of "knowledge crystals" that contain kryptonian teachings as well as the ability to create a 'fortress of solitude' from solid ice.

[image]

Similar crystals are found in Superman Returns
[image]