# What is the significance Superman's suit?

Tags: dc, superman

What is the significance of a long piece of red colored cloth in Superman's suit?

Comment: Isn't that like the dress code in Krypton?

Comment: Just clarifying, are you referring to his cape or something else? (Which I can only surmise would be the undies-on-the-outside?)

Comment: Why should it even have any significance?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Why did Jonathan and Martha Kent attach a Cape to Superman's costume?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25123/why-did-jonathan-and-martha-kent-attach-a-cape-to-supermans-costume)

Answer (score 3):

There is a (unreferenced) discussion of the costume and the cape [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060831044212AAppAVm). In short, the cape is apparently meant to function as a pocket where he can keep items including his Clark Kent clothes.

(This seems a little funny to me, but that is what this guy, who may or may not be making it up, is saying. If anyone can find something that backs him up I'll edit and add it in. I haven't read the comics and I'm not intimately familiar with this part of his backstory, so for now this is the only in-universe answer I can find. Interestingly, the [Superman wikia](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Wiki) doesn't seem to have any detailed discussion of the costume or cape as far as I can see.)

Also, the "real life" rationale for the cape, according to Jerry Siegel as quoted in Superman: The Complete History by Les Daniels (via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman)), is that they wanted to make the character as colourful and distinctive as they could. Not sure if this is what you're after, but hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, in the Before Time, during the Silver Age, Pre-Crisis Superman did indeed, compress his clothing at superspeed and store them in a pocket hidden in his cape. Back then his cape was as indestructible as he was so, there was no chance they would be lost or damage while there...Don't think to hard about it, your brain just hurts when you do...