# How does Superman get indestructible costume everytime after he loses existing one?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

[Superman's costume is made from the blanket which he was wrapped in when he first landed on Earth.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22724/931) The alien properties of the blanket make the costume nearly indestructible. But, I think its stock is limited & it doesn't have replication/ regeneration properties etc. (Correct me if I am wrong).

In an episode of *Justice League*, Toyman sent Superman to the future, when the Sun was red. Unfortunately, it looks like the costume also needs yellow Sun for indestructibility. Look what happened:
[image]
How did he come back in action with an indestructible costume?

In *Justice League Unlimited*, once the government's Cadmus project created a monster with Superman's DNA who was powerful enough to tear Superman's costume apart:
[image]
But again, it was not a big problem for Superman. I don't know from where Superman got a shiny new costume in the same episode.

Does Superman have access to Kryptonian cloth reservoirs?  Are there other things I am missing?
What's the secret behind this?

Comment: I think they are all different costume, when one got ripped he wears other one. Even in Batman Beyond he wears White colored costume in one episode.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yup, its very likely that they are all different costumes, but the problem is indestructibility of all those costumes as stock of Kryptonian blanket was limited.

Comment: Not in the Batman beyond costume http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://www.blogcdn.com/www.comicsalliance.com/media/2010/06/batmanbeyond3a.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.comicsalliance.com/2010/06/29/batman-beyond-best-episode/&h=400&w=584&sz=27&tbnid=-6wzdlaAnIMD2M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=131&zoom=1&usg=__kU5GYv97IO-4ZzqDNHkc2rOmJRE=&docid=YhecnZGJxn2ofM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2n96UZPDGYanrAeExoG4Bw&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQ9QEwAg&dur=340

Comment: The indestructible costume was cut by... regular shears. And then sewn together by... a Singer sewing machine... or perhaps by hand... strong hands. The whole idea from start to finish is stupid. These early era comics didn't put much effort into "fleshing out" the universe like we expect today some 50+ years later.

Answer (score 20):

The concept of his costume being made of the blanket he was wrapped in was a [Pre-Crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths) explanation for how his clothing could be invulnerable, in the Post-Crisis series written by John Byrne called [Man of Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_of_Steel_%28comics%29), his invulnerability is explained as a protective aura that extends to the clothing touching his skin.  This is how he can have a torn or shredded costume in one scene and a fresh one a short time later.  His costume is made of normal Earth materials, he keeps a stash of them at his Fortress.  The Superman of the [DC Animated Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_and_abilities_of_Superman#DC_Animated_Universe) is essentially the Post-Crisis John Byrne Superman with a few slight changes for plot purposes.

Comment: This isn't the case atleast in *Superman: The Animated Series*.. As I've remembered, Clark Kent's costume has been destroyed by bombs, missile several times leaving Superman costume on his body.

Comment: @SachinShekhar His invulnerability (which would extend to his costume) was "dumbed down" for dramatic effect.  If he truly was as invulnerable as he has been depicted the writters would have to justify anything other than magic or Kryptonite actually being a threat to him.

Comment: This actually became an issue in the DCAU,  with fans calling the writers on having Superman be taken out too easily, just to show how tough a bad guy was. They were pretty much redeemed at the end of the Return of Darkseid arc when he made his "world of cardboard" speech in the JLU episode "Apocalypse."