# How does Superman avoid deafening everyone with his sonic booms?

Tags: dc, superman

I recently read that military jets don't normally go supersonic over land because their sonic booms would cause disruption, which I didn't know. It got me thinking about how fast Superman goes. He'd pretty much deafen anyone within a few hundred metres of him if he went supersonic over land. Is this ever addressed?

Comment: Why ask this question of Superman, and not the Flash, who is considerably faster (despite *The Simpsons*)? It would seem like this would be far more of a problem for the latter, or one of the many other superheroes who focus on super-speed rather than the variety of abilities Superman has.

Comment: Because Superman's abilities are entirely natural and therefore he's really just brute-forcing it. Where The Flash, for instance, could be excused because his speed is a lot more complicated. There could be reasons why he doesn't create that sonic boom, same as anyone who flies or runs using magic.

Comment: That makes sense... I think. It is a head-scratcher. To be fair, most superpowers don't make any sense whatsoever. *Cracked* did an article on all the superpowers that would have undesirable side effects once, and Superman clearly inspired most of them.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. I actually did some quick calculations for this question to see what other side effects there would be. To go half the circumference of the Earth in 20 minutes he'd be going at 16,000 M/S. That's around 0.01% the speed of light.

Comment: @JamesSheridan part of the Flash's abilitiesis the creation of a "friction-less aura" that protects him from the negative side effects of extreme acceleration and deceleration, like wind sheer, constant impacts to the bottom of his feet etc.  That aura also protects his environment from things like sonic booms. Supes doesn't have that so like PointlessSpike said, he's using brute strength.

Comment: Superman's powers are magical too. Remember the aura which protects his costume?

Comment: @Sacin Shekar: there's no such aura, it's a super-strong fabric: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22729/4918

Comment: @b_jonas There are several continuities of Superman..

Comment: @b_jonas See this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34718/how-does-superman-get-indestructible-costume-everytime-after-he-loses-existing-o

Comment: @SachinShekhar that's not magic, it's an extension of his invulnerability.

Comment: @Monty Magic is high level science...

Comment: @SachinShekhar I think you mean "magic is just science we don't understand yet", which is probably true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is overtly addressed in Superman #217.  Lois Lane and Jimmy Olsen are being held hostage and Superman's way of dealing with the terrorists is to blow through the region without regard for collateral effects.  The sonic boom in his wake acts as a flashbang might and disorientates and disables the terrorists so that Superman can rescue Lois and Jimmy without incident.

[image: Superman #217]

Comment: An excellent answer. You have my +1. So the answer is that the writers hand-waved it away.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Related: [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58516/why-doesnt-quicksilver-create-sonic-booms#comment116322_58516) on my earlier question about Quicksilver's lack of sonic booms.</sup>

Let's ask NASA about [sonic booms](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/news/FactSheets/FS-016-DFRC.html#.VFZFShZ3PlE)

> **There are several factors that can influence sonic booms - weight, size, and shape of the aircraft or vehicle, plus its altitude, attitude and flight path, and weather or atmospheric conditions.  A larger and heavier aircraft must displace more air and create more lift to sustain flight, compared with small, light aircraft. Therefore, they will create sonic booms stronger and louder than those of smaller, lighter aircraft. The larger and heavier the aircraft, the stronger the shock waves will be.**
>
> Altitude determines the distance shock waves travel before reaching the ground, and this has the most significant effect on intensity. As the shock cone gets wider, and it moves outward and downward, its strength is reduced. Generally, the higher the aircraft, the greater the distance the shock wave must travel, reducing the intensity of the sonic boom. Of all the factors influencing sonic booms, increasing altitude is the most effective method of reducing sonic boom intensity.
>
> The width of the boom "carpet" beneath the aircraft is about one mile for each 1000 feet of altitude. An aircraft, for example, flying supersonic at 50,000 feet can produce a sonic boom cone about 50 miles wide. The sonic boom, however, will not be uniform. Maximum intensity is directly beneath the aircraft, and decreases as the lateral distance from the flight path increases until it ceases to exist because the shock waves refract away from the ground. The lateral spreading of the sonic boom depends only upon altitude, speed and the atmosphere - and is independent of the vehicle's shape, size, and weight.
>
> **The ratio of aircraft length to maximum cross sectional area also influences the intensity of the sonic boom. The longer and more slender the aircraft, the weaker the shock waves. The fatter and more blunt the vehicle, the stronger the shock wave can be.**
>
> Increasing speeds above Mach 1.3 results in only small changes in shock wave strength.
>
> The direction of travel and strength of shock waves are influenced by wind, speed, and direction, and by air temperature and pressure. At speeds slightly greater than Mach 1, their effect can be significant, but their influence is small at speeds greater than Mach 1.3. Distortions in the shape of the sonic boom signatures can also be influenced by local air turbulence near the ground. This, too, will cause variations in the overpressure levels.
>
> Aircraft maneuvering can cause distortions in shock wave patterns. Some maneuvers - pushovers, acceleration and "S" turns - can amplify the intensity of the shock wave. Hills, valleys and other terrain features can create multiple reflections of the shock waves and affect intensity.

The size and strength of sonic booms are affected by the size and shape of the object. While Superman certainly *does* create sonic booms, the ones he creates would be relatively small and non-dangerous. How non-dangerous?

NASA continues

> Overpressure
>
> Sonic booms are measured in pounds per square foot of overpressure. This is the amount of the increase over the normal atmospheric pressure which surrounds us (2,116 psf/14.7 psi).  At one pound overpressure, no damage to structures would be expected. Overpressures of 1 to 2 pounds are produced by supersonic aircraft flying at normal operating altitudes. Some public reaction could be expected between 1.5 and 2 lb.  Rare minor damage may occur with 2 to 5 lb overpressure.
>
> As overpressure increases, the likelihood of structural damage and stronger public reaction also increases. Tests, however, have shown that structures in good condition have been undamaged by overpressures of up to 11 lb.  Sonic booms produced by aircraft flying supersonic at altitudes of less than 100 feet, creating between 20 and 144 lb overpressure, have been experienced by humans without injury.
>
> Damage to eardrums can be expected when overpressures reach 720 lb. Overpressures of 2160 lb would have to be generated to produce lung damage.
>
> Typical overpressure of aircraft types are:
>
> - SR-71: 0.9 lb, speed of Mach 3, 80,000 feet
> - Concorde SST: 1.94 lb, speed of Mach 2, 52,000 feet
> - F-104: 0.8 lb, speed of Mach 1.93, 48,000 feet
> - Space Shuttle: 1.25 lb, speed of Mach 1.5, 60,000 feet, landing approach

Even crafts much larger than Superman do not typically create pressures large enough to damage people or property (granted, they are typically at higher altitudes).

Comment: For the record, the sonic booms that a human-sized object would create would be both instantly and long-term hazardous to human health; http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lzsbbgOzPo0C&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=sonic+boom+inside+a+room&source=bl&ots=NIUH_x39rQ&sig=c6QSfx-ljW6UUwkgwTXDU-3r0LM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=50ZWVMa3Go_e7AbE4YDQCw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=sonic%20boom%20inside%20a%20room&f=false, not to mention damaging to property (especially plasterboard) and any glass in the immediate and non-immediate vicinity

Comment: Further to Richard's comment, Superman would likely be able to accelerate much quicker than an aircraft, increasing the overpressure.